# When adding external jar file showing broken in netbeans

Tags: netbeans

When adding external jar file path is broken showing the error message in NetBeans. How to resolve the problem? I tried to do by one by one, it is not importing in java file. I am creating application in JavaFX.

Comment: When are you getting this error? while adding the file or while running the application?

Comment: @NeerajKumar no .. application open and then adding jar files

Comment: Check this https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=158109